# Kotlin copy() function is creating a new Id on a JPA Entity resulting in a new row

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have an update method on a spring controller which takes in a request and uses copy to copy the contents into a loaded entity. As soon as copy() is called, the id property on the entity is changed to a new one.

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
    fun update(@PathVariable id: UUID, @RequestBody request: UpdateSocietyRequest): ResponseEntity<SocietyUpdatedResponse> {
        val society = societyRepository.findById(id).orElse(null) ?: return notFound().build()
        val updatedSociety = society.copy(
                name = request.name,
                phone = request.phone,
                address = Address(
                        request.addressLine1,
                        request.addressLine2,
                        request.addressLine3,
                        request.city,
                        request.state,
                        request.zipCode
                )
        )
        societyRepository.save(updatedSociety)
        return ok(SocietyUpdatedResponse(updatedSociety.id, updatedSociety.name, updatedSociety.phone))
    }
```

Entity.kt

```
@MappedSuperclass
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = ["createdOn, updatedOn"], allowGetters = true)
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener::class)
abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID()

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    var createdOn: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()

    @Column(nullable = true)
    @LastModifiedDate
    var updatedOn: LocalDateTime? = null

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreatedBy
    var createdBy: String? = null

    @Column(nullable = true)
    @LastModifiedBy
    var updatedBy: String? = null
}

@Embeddable
data class Address(val addressLine1: String,
                   val addressLine2: String,
                   val addressLine3: String,
                   val city: String,
                   val state: String,
                   val zipCode: Int)

@Entity
data class Society(
        @NotNull
        val name: String,

        @NotNull
        val phone: String,

        @Embedded
        val address: Address
) : BaseEntity()
```

As far as I know, copy shouldn't created a new object but changes the existing with the new valued from the request. Why id being assigned a new UUID?

Thanks

Comment: copy() as its name indicates, creates a copy of the object. If it mutated the original object, its vals would be mutated, and vals can't be mutated.

Comment: Yes, so updatedSociety is a copy of the society object loaded from repository and updated with the values inside copy....why would there be a new UUID on updatedSociety?

Comment: Because the only copied properties are the ones declared in the primary constructor of the data class. `id` is a val, initialized with `new UUID()` by the super class. And a val, once again, can't possibly be reassigned. So it can't possibly have any other value than `new UUID()`. Besides, the documentation says: *Note that the compiler only uses the properties defined inside the primary constructor for the automatically generated functions.*. Other note: why do you assign a UUID by yourself, and also specify that the uuid is supposed to be generated by JPA?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#properties-declared-in-the-class-body) only properties defined between parentheses will be used in the copy() function then id and other properties that inherited from the superclass will not be used. I tested it.

> Properties Declared in the Class Body
>
> Note that the compiler only uses
> the properties defined inside the primary constructor for the
> automatically generated functions. To exclude a property from the
> generated implementations, declare it inside the class body:
>
> data class Person(val name: String) { var age: Int = 0 }
>
> Only the property name will be used inside the toString(), equals(), hashCode(), and copy() implementations, and
> there will only be one component function component1(). While two
> Person objects can have different ages, they will be treated as equal.

However, my solution is:

Do not use the `copy()` function. Just change the properties of `society` and save it. You can change the properties of a `val` but you can not change the reference (`society = something` is forbidden).

When you use `copy()`, it generates a new object in heap and its reference is deferent(`hashCode()` is deferent).

So I think changing the Society class properties to var and using the following code must be good:

```
@Entity
data class Society(
        @NotNull
        var name: String,

        @NotNull
        var phone: String,

        @Embedded
        var address: Address
) : BaseEntity()

...

@PutMapping("/{id}")
    fun update(@PathVariable id: UUID, @RequestBody request: UpdateSocietyRequest): ResponseEntity<SocietyUpdatedResponse> {
        val society = societyRepository.findById(id).orElse(null) ?: return notFound().build()
        society.name = request.name
        society.phone = request.phone
        society.address = Address(
                        request.addressLine1,
                        request.addressLine2,
                        request.addressLine3,
                        request.city,
                        request.state,
                        request.zipCode
                )
        )
        societyRepository.save(society)
        return ok(SocietyUpdatedResponse(society.id, society.name, society.phone))
    }
```

Also, I think using inheritance in data classes can make confusion so it is better to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks Mostafa, the above code would work if I change the properties to a var.